# Javascript - Create a array of objects to get a function to work

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

this is my first question in this forum.

I think this is a real Beginner question, please dont judge me.
In need to get a js function to work. It already works if i call the function with some hand made testdata:

```
      graph.addWaypoint('0', {1:100});  
      graph.addWaypointx('1', {0: 100,2: 200,4: 100});  
      graph.addWaypoint('2', {1: 200,3: 300,9: 100});
      graph.addWaypoint('4', {1: 100,5: 100});
      graph.addWaypoint('5', {4: 100});
```

This works perfectly.
But I need to call this function with some more waypoints in a for-loop.

I got this function here that cound return the needed data but i dont know how to get the date in a form that works:

```
 function create_all_connections(waypoint_array, neighbor_matrix) {
   var connections = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < waypoint_array.length; i++) {
        connections[i]={};
        for (var j = 0; j < waypoint_array.length; j++) {
            if (neighbor_matrix[i][j] === 1) {
                var x1 = waypoint_array[i][0];
                var y1 = waypoint_array[i][1];
                var x2 = waypoint_array[j][0];
                var y2 = waypoint_array[j][1];
                var distance = distance_between(x1, y1, x2, y2);

                console.log('Point ' + i + ' connected to ' + j+' Distance: '+distance);
            }
        }
    }
    return connections;
}
```

This function returns something like this:

```
Point 0 connected to 1 Distance: 100 
Point 1 connected to 0 Distance: 100 
Point 1 connected to 2 Distance: 200 
Point 1 connected to 4 Distance: 100 
Point 2 connected to 1 Distance: 200 
Point 2 connected to 3 Distance: 300 
Point 2 connected to 9 Distance: 100 
Point 3 connected to 2 Distance: 300 
Point 4 connected to 1 Distance: 100 
Point 4 connected to 5 Distance: 100 
Point 5 connected to 4 Distance: 100 
Point 6 connected to 7 Distance: 100 
Point 6 connected to 8 Distance: 400 
Point 6 connected to 9 Distance: 200 
Point 7 connected to 6 Distance: 100 
Point 8 connected to 6 Distance: 400 
Point 9 connected to 2 Distance: 100 
Point 9 connected to 6 Distance: 200
```

when i match the variable names of the two functions it should be something like this:

graph.addwaypoint(i, {j:distance})//j:distance is eventually inserted multiple times.

I hope you understand what my problem is, and that someone could help me.

Bob

Comment: What if you concatenate the variables: 'graph.addwaypoint("\""+i+"\"", "{"+j+":"+distance+"}")' ?

Comment: i tried, but i dont get it to work, but when i log my arguments to console it seems to has the right form

Comment: now i tried this a lot and i didnt get it to work,  is it possible that i need a real object  for this function and not a string that looks like a object?

Comment: yes, that is my opinion too. But I don't know how to help you with that.